# Dropdowns not working in Phonegap app on lower versions of Android

Tags: android, cordova, android-2.3-gingerbread, iscroll

I am working on a Phonegap mobile application. It has select boxes, input fields and other html tags. Application is working fine on higher versions of Android but in lower versions (Gingerbread)  options are not getting selected. On selecting a dropdown, options of some other dropdown are opening.

I have tried adding data-native-menu="false" attribute to the select menu as well as tried increasing z-index but none of this is working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding focus to the element once it is clicked.